# Cannot use LogisticRegression for multilabel classification

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, multilabel-classification

I'm using `LogisticRegression` from the `sklearn` library along with `MultiOutputClassifier` in order to use LR for multilabel classification. Unfortunately I'm getting an error when running this code:

```py
res = MultiOutputClassifier(estimator=LogisticRegression()).fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes in the data,
but the data contains only one class: 0
```

This does not make sense to me because `x_train` has shape (2210, 2000) while `y_train` has shape (2210, 58), which means it has 58 classes.

```
y_train = array([[0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
   ...,
   [0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]])
```

x_train represents an array containing embeddings using Bag of Words term frequency inverse document frequency:

```
x_train = array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.02571182, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.11247333, 0.        , ..., 0.09392727, 0.        ,
    0.        ],
   ...,
   [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.07308953, 0.        , ..., 0.09155637, 0.        ,
    0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.07492016, 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        ]])
```

Comment: Careful... you have 58 **targets**, not 58 **classes** (unless `y` has been encoded with one-hot encoding?). The number of classes you have corresponds to the number of unique values in `y`. It would probably help to see some of your data.

Comment: Hi @kwinkunks yes it is one-hot encoded

Comment: In general, I'd stick to one-hot encoding for **features**, not the target. Why not leave the labels unencoded (`sklearn` is okay with this now) and pass in a 1D array for the target? Then it's an ordinary multiclass problem and you can use classifiers directly.

Comment: @kwinkunks But if it is an ordinary multiclass problem stops being a multilabel problem? correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Correct, if there's only one set of related classes (dog, cat, horse), it's a multiclass problem. If you have another set of classes (brown, black, grey) then you would have a multilabel problem. (Most problems are not expressed as mutilabel problems.)

Comment: @kwinkunks in this case I must express the problem as a multilabel one, I was able to apply logistic regression, by using OnevsRestClassifier instead of MultiOutputClassifier

Answer (score 0):

Your `MultiOutputClassifier` is training a new Logistic Regression for each class, in such a way that the i-th logistic regressor is trained on `y_train[:,i]` (a column vector). The error

```
ValueError: This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes in the data,
but the data contains only one class: 0
```

is given by `Logistic Regression` and is indicating that one of these column vectors (`y_train[:,i]`) has only zeroes (i.e, only the class 0). Logistic Regression (and many other binary classifiers) can't be trained on a dataset where only exists a single class.
You can check the class distribution of each class by running

```py
np.mean(y_train,axis=0)
```

and, consequently, check which class has only zeroes.

#### Approach 1

In supervised learning, if a class has only negative samples (only zeroes), it is reasonable to only output zero, since there is nothing that can be learned from the positive class.
In `scikit-learn`, some algorithms from supervised learning will always output zero for this class that only has zeroes. Some examples are: `KNeighborsClassifier` and `DecisionTreeClassifier`.
Or you can just discard this column vector that has only zeroes:

```py
new_y = y_train[:,y_train.sum(axis=0)!=0]
```

#### Approach 2

But if your testing data actually has zeroes and ones for all classes, you may want to reconsider regenerating your training data in such a way that all classes have negative and positive samples in the training data. Search for stratification for multi-label data, such as [iterative-stratification](https://github.com/trent-b/iterative-stratification).

#### Approach 3

If this training data is not possible for some reason, you may want to take a look at one-class classification algorithms or novelty detection. These algorithms can learn from training data that only has "normal" samples, that is, all samples belong to the same class.